# Return a sorted list from an array of linked lists in c

Tags: arrays, c, sorting, struct, linked-list

What I'm trying to accomplish here at the end is to sort a struct array that has multiple linked lists in it and return 1 merged list and sorted.

Example

```
Input: [1->4->5, 1->3->4, 2->6] 
Output: 1->1->2->3->4->4->5->6
```

The input is the array which as it shows in the example has 3 different lists in it sorted wrong.

The output is the final sorted list.

What I tried to do is trying to access the array like a normal struct array and then sort it 2 at a time.

My code

```
#include <stddef.h>


#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE
typedef struct s_listnode
{
    int val;
    struct s_listnode* next;
} listnode;
#endif

#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_ARRAY
typedef struct s_listnode_array
{
    int size;
    listnode **array;
} listnode_array;
#endif


listnode* sort(listnode* first, listnode* second){
    listnode* newNode;
    if(first == NULL && second == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (first == NULL)
        return second;
    if (second == NULL)
        return first;

// checking if the value on the first list bigger than the second or equal
    if (first->val >= second->val) {\
   // if yes that means that the second should be first.
        newNode = second;
        newNode->next = sort(first, second->next);
    } else {
        newNode = first;
        newNode->next = sort(first->next, second);
    }
    return newNode;
}

listnode* merge_k_sorted_lists(listnode_array* head)
{
    listnode *newNode;
   for(int i = 0 ; i < head->size; i++){
       newNode = sort(head->array[0], head->array[i]);
   }

   return newNode;
}
```

When I try to run my code I get no return value at all.

Comment: Time to learn how to use a *debugger* to step through your code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values. And step *into* the recursive calls to `sort`. I also recommend that you at the same time use pen and paper to "draw" the list as it's built up. All that should make it easier to see how `newNode` changes, and to what it changes to, in the `merge_k_sorted_lists` function.

Comment: Your function called `sort` is really doing a `merge`.

Comment: The first iteration of the loop in `merge_k_sorted_lists` is using list 0 for both parameters of `sort`.

Answer (score 0):

I've made some changes and now it seems to work better but there is an issue.

if the input is an array that has [[],[1]] and the expected output should be [1] I don't get a return and I get SIGSEGV (signal 11)

```
#include <stddef.h>


#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE
typedef struct s_listnode
{
    int val;
    struct s_listnode* next;
} listnode;
#endif

#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_ARRAY
typedef struct s_listnode_array
{
    int size;
    listnode **array;
} listnode_array;
#endif


listnode* sort(listnode* first, listnode* second){
     
    if(first == NULL && second == NULL)
        return NULL;
    if (first == NULL){
        return second;
    }
    if (second == NULL)
        return first;

    
    listnode* newNode;
    
    if (first->val > second->val) {
        newNode = second;
        newNode->next = sort(first, second->next);
    } else {
        newNode = first;
        newNode->next = sort(first->next, second);
    }
    return newNode;
}


listnode* merge_k_sorted_lists(listnode_array* nodeArr)
{
    listnode *newNode;
    
    if(nodeArr->array[0]->next == NULL) 
        return nodeArr->array[0];
    if(nodeArr->size < 2)
        return nodeArr->array[0];

    for(int i = 1 ; i < nodeArr->size; i++)
        newNode = sort(nodeArr->array[0], nodeArr->array[i]);

   return newNode;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed and simplified merge_k_sorted_lists(). Removed an unneeded if statement from sort().  This is essentially the same as the second loop in a bottom up merge sort for linked lists. The recursive sort(), which is really a merge, will result in stack overflow for large lists.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Bottom-up_implementation_using_lists

```
#include <stdio.h>

#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE
typedef struct s_listnode
{
    int val;
    struct s_listnode* next;
} listnode;
#endif

#ifndef STRUCT_LISTNODE_ARRAY
#define STRUCT_LISTNODE_ARRAY
typedef struct s_listnode_array
{
    int size;
    listnode **array;
} listnode_array;
#endif

listnode* sort(listnode* first, listnode* second){
listnode* newNode;
    if (first == NULL)
        return second;
    if (second == NULL)
        return first;
    if (first->val > second->val) {
        newNode = second;
        newNode->next = sort(first, second->next);
    } else {
        newNode = first;
        newNode->next = sort(first->next, second);
    }
    return newNode;
}

listnode* merge_k_sorted_lists(listnode_array* nodeArr)
{
listnode *newNode = NULL;
    for(int i = 0 ; i < nodeArr->size; i++)
        newNode = sort(newNode, nodeArr->array[i]);
    return newNode;
}

int main()
{
listnode list0[3] = {{1, list0+1}, {4,list0+2}, {5,NULL}};
listnode list1[3] = {{1, list1+1}, {3,list1+2}, {4,NULL}};
listnode list2[2] = {{2, list2+1}, {6,NULL}};
listnode *lists[3] = {list0, list1, list2};
listnode_array array[3] = {3, lists};
listnode *result, *tmp;
    result = merge_k_sorted_lists(array);
    for(tmp = result; tmp; tmp = tmp->next)
        printf("%1d ", tmp->val);
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

---

Non-recursive merge using dummy node

```
listnode* sort(listnode* first, listnode* second){
listnode dMrg = {0, NULL};              /* dummy node */
listnode *pMrg = &dMrg;                 /* ptr to node in merged list */
    if (first == NULL)                  /* check for empty lists */
        return second;
    if (second == NULL)
        return first;
    while(1){                           /* merge the lists */
        if(first->val > second->val){
            pMrg = pMrg->next = second;
            second = second->next;
            if(second == NULL){
                pMrg->next = first;
                break;
            }
        }else{
            pMrg = pMrg->next = first;
            first = first->next;
            if(first == NULL){
                pMrg->next = second;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return dMrg.next;                   /* return merged list */
}
```

---

Non-recursive merge using pointer to pointer

```
listnode* sort(listnode* first, listnode* second){
listnode *pMrg;                         /* merged list */
listnode **ppMrg = &pMrg;               /* ptr to ptr to node in merged list */
    if (first == NULL)                  /* check for empty lists */
        return second;
    if (second == NULL)
        return first;
    while(1){                           /* merge the lists */
        if(first->val > second->val){
            *ppMrg = second;
            ppMrg = &(second->next);
            second = *ppMrg;
            if(second == NULL){
                *ppMrg = first;
                break;
            }
        }else{
            *ppMrg = first;
            ppMrg = &(first->next);
            first = *ppMrg;
            if(first == NULL){
                *ppMrg = second;
                break;
            }
        }
    }
    return pMrg;
}
```